# Laser_scan_matcher gmapping and stage

Tags: navigation, simulation, stage, gmapping, laser-scan-matcher

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I'm trying to build a system utilizing gmapping and laser_scan_matcher ( laser_scan_matcher to improve the odometry of my robot).
I've already made the system work utilizing the bag that came with laser_scan_matcher.
Using

Fixed_Frame: odom
Base_Frame: base_link

But when I try to use the same setup in conjunction with stage, a concurrent tf transform problem arises.

I kind of understand the problem the laser_scan_matcher publishes the odom to base_footprint and stageros does also.

But I'm lost how to solve it i tried to modify stageros to not publish the transform but laser scan matcher needs the inicial transform.

Thanks in advance

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11732/laser_scan_matcher-gmapping-and-stage/) by [fmarques](https://answers.ros.org/users/1293/fmarques/) on ROS Answers with karma: 92 on 2011-10-29

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Brian Gerkey](https://answers.ros.org/users/8/brian-gerkey/) on 2011-10-31**:
Unfortunately, `stageros` uses hardcoded frame names.  But `gmapping`'s frame names are configurable via parameters. Can you change the frame names used by `laser_scan_matcher`?  If so, you should be able to configure the system to run all three components without conflicts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> I kind of understand the problem the laser_scan_matcher publishes the odom to base_footprint and stageros does also.

That would create a problem, yes. Only one node should be publishing that transform. I'm not familiar with how `stageros` works, but if it's publishing the odom->base_link transform, you need to disable that.

> laser scan matcher needs the inicial transform.

That shouldn't be the case. The only `tf` that `laser_scan_matcher` requires is `base_link` -> `laser`. That can be published by a static tf publisher, or by stage.

`laser_scan_matcher` is intended as a replacement for odometry, for robots without odom sensors. If your robot already has an odometry sensor, then you can provide its measurements as an optional input to `laser_scan_matcher`, and the scan matcher will refine them. The odom sensor's measurements would need to be published on a topic (not as a `tf`). I would get the base case working first though (no odometry) and then attempt this case.

Could you describe your use case in a little more detail? You are working with simulated data? What sensors does the robot have?

Also, attaching the console output would be helpful, so we can see what warnings/errors you are getting.

Ivan

---

Originally posted by [Ivan Dryanovski](https://answers.ros.org/users/79/ivan-dryanovski/) with karma: 4954 on 2011-10-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [fmarques](https://answers.ros.org/users/1293/fmarques/) on 2011-10-31**:
So I did change the stageros cpp to not publish the odom-> base_fooprint( base_link) and that solved the problem everything running smooth now. It works fine using the odom topic or not.  So thank you very much.